# Can my answer be undeleted?

Tags: discussion, deleted-answers

I just posted an answer to this question here [Accessing the Mount Teide summit without permit](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/19433/accessing-the-mount-teide-summit-without-permit/108121) , and somebody deleted it.

I must say I'm rather annoyed by this. When I travelled to Tenerife I had precisely this question in my mind, and found it in this website, but it had no useful answer. I had to find out by myself how to climb the Teide without a permit.

Being of a generous heart, I decided to share my knowledge here to save future travellers the trouble and bam, my answer disappears.

I don't really know how this works, but I guess somebody here could restore my answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

I am responsible for deleting your answer after it was flagged. The reason I deleted it is that we do not condone posts in which people explain how to do things that are illegal. In my opinion your answer does exactly that:

> [...] You just need to go around the guards [...]